# How to destroy cart and forget session after a event fire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, payment

**I'm using laravel 8.**

**I want to destroy the cart and forget the session after PaymentSucceeded event fire.**

Here is my `EventServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],

    PaymentSucceeded::class => [
        Destroy::class,
    ],

];


public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    //
}
```

and here is `Listeners/Destroy.php`

```
public function handle(PaymentSucceeded $event)
{
    Cart::destroy();
    if (Session::has('coupon'))
       {
           Session::forget('coupon');
       }
}
```

**But it's not working.** Now What can I do?

Comment: Please explain not working, any error occurs ?

Comment: No error. But, it's not destroying cart and session.